# IJCADのLISPで任意の座標を囲むポリラインを取得したい

Tags: ijcad, lisp

IJCAD2023 STDにAutoCADからAutoLISPで開発したツールの移行をしています。
(ssget)関数の座標フィルタを使用して、任意の座標を囲むポリラインを取得したいのですが、うまくいかない場合があります。
以下のコードを実行した場合、ss3のみ選択セットが取得できており、ポリラインの第一点のみが評価されていると思われます。
AutoCADでは全ての選択セットが取得できていました。

```
(command "pline" "0,0" "100,0" "100,100" "0,100" "c")
(setq ss1 (ssget "x" (list(cons -4 ">,>,*")(cons 10 (list 50 50)))))
(setq ss2 (ssget "x" (list(cons -4 ">,<,*")(cons 10 (list 50 50)))))
(setq ss3 (ssget "x" (list(cons -4 "<,<,*")(cons 10 (list 50 50)))))
(setq ss4 (ssget "x" (list(cons -4 "<,>,*")(cons 10 (list 50 50)))))
```

ss1～ss4の全ての選択セットが取得できるよう、ポリラインの第二点以降も評価対象となるような方法はありますでしょうか？